# How can I use Expression.Lambda for SELECT LINQ operation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, expression-trees

I'll start from afar a little. My task is to copy all tables from legacy database to antoher db. The tables of this database were not created by me and it was a long time ago. That's why paginations I use to copy these tables differ a little.
First pagination I use works fine. I filter entities using Expression trees and it works with good performance. The code is below.

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDbSet));
var property = Expression.Property(parameter, primaryKeyProperty.Name);
var body = Expression.GreaterThan(property,Expression.Constant(id, typeof(TId)));

entities = await _dbFirst.Set<TDbSet>().AsNoTracking()
      .Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TDbSet, bool>>(body, parameter))
      .Take(PAGE_SIZE)
      .ToListAsync()
      .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**Now is the problem**. Class for copying table works with generic type parameter TId. For tables with composite PK I take one PK type, and then Select all its Ids through TDbSet (you better look the code below and you'll understand what I am talking about). By these distinct list of id's I take entities from one DB and copy them to another DB.
I don't know how to use SELECT operation with Expression trees. That's why I take Id's value by type. It takes 5seconds every time I take them, it is very bad performance because table can contain millions of rows.

```
var allPkIds = _dbFirst.Set<TDbSet>().AsNoTracking()
         .Select(e => e.GetType().GetProperty(primaryKeyProperty.Name).GetValue(e))
         .Distinct()
         .OrderBy(o => o)
         .Skip(alreadyTakenIdsCounter)
         .Take(COMMIT_SIZE_FOR_COMPOSITE_PK)
         .ToArray();
alreadyTakenIdsCounter += COMMIT_SIZE_FOR_COMPOSITE_PK;

foreach (var entityId in allPkIds)
{
  var body = Expression.Equal(property, Expression.Constant(entityId));

  var entities = await _dbFirst.Set<TDbSet>().AsNoTracking()
                             .Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TDbSet, bool>>(body, parameter))
                             .ToListAsync()
                             .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**Now is the question**. How can I use Expression.Lambda for such select operation? I googled a lot and read Microsoft documentation but I can't find answer.

Comment: *My task is to copy all tables from legacy database to antoher db*, first sentence tells me that you have chosen bad library for ETL task. [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) will copy million rows in minute even without pagination. And I has LINQ support, no raw SQL is needed.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thank you for your advice but I can use only EntityFramework. I didn't set this condition and I can't change it. Class is almost ready but I need is to find out how to use Expression Trees for linq select operation, that's the point.

Comment: *but I can use only EntityFramework* for task which is not suitable for this ORM. Ok, show your generic method signature and why it is needed to care about PK.

Comment: And better to show whole method. I can rewrite this to performant variant. By selecting records one by one, your *task* will take forever.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I need to care about composite PKs because my default generic pagination takes 1000(for example) entities with PKs more than last Id(one from composite Pks). If I use such pagination for table with composite PK it skips some rows. That's why I started to use my second pagination for composite PKs. It works but it will be much faster if I use Expression Tree for select linq operation. Is it possible?
Here's my generic method signature:
`async Task CopyTableAsync<TDbSet, TId>(PropertyInfo primaryKeyProperty, bool isDescending, TId id, bool isPkComposite) where TDbSet :class`

Comment: Show, full method (edit question). I need to understand logic. And why this method do not have parameters `SourceDbConext` and `DestinationDbContext`.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv the whole method is rather big...

Comment: Also, with EF you will fail if PKs are Identity columns, even do not understand how you will fix that

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have public fields for dbFirst and dbSecond it was initialized earlier

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I used SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF and it works

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I also use NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
My db copied all but not so fast as I want, about 4-5 hours. All because of pagination for composite Pk

Comment: How about signature `CopyTableAsync<TEntity, TId>(DbContext source, DbContext target, Expression<Func<TEnitty, TId>> primaryKey, bool isDescending)` ? Which seems more logical for me.

Comment: Really, so much efforts to stick with EF for one time task. With `linq2db` it will be just `target.BulkCopy(source.GetTable<T>().AsEnumerable())` with BulkCopy options which disables Identity Insert.

Comment: Actually you can do that with [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore). Something like that: `target.BulkCopy(new BulkCopyOptions { KeepIdentity = true }, source.Set<T>().AsEnumerable())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```cs
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDbSet), "e");
var selectLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TDbSet, TId>>(
    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, primaryKeyProperty), param);

var allPkIds = _dbFirst.Set<TDbSet>().AsNoTracking()
         .Select(selectLambda)
         .Distinct()
         .OrderBy(o => o)
         .Skip(alreadyTakenIdsCounter)
         .Take(COMMIT_SIZE_FOR_COMPOSITE_PK)
         .ToArray();
```